# Integrate an already created Azure Application Insight with an API App in App Service using Azure Resource Manager

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

I am creating an app insight in a different resource group using a Terraform Script.
I want to associate the previously created App Insight in when i create a web app or an API app.
I am passing the Intrumentation key of the previuosly created app insight in the web app however they are not getting linked. 
When i try to create the app insight from within the same ARM template where the Web App is created it works fine.

**Sample ARM that works fine:**

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "webSiteName": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 1,
            "defaultValue": "TestWebsiteWithAppInsight",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Describes the name of the new website"
            }
        },
        "appInsightsName": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 1,
            "defaultValue": "TestAppInsight",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Describes the name of the Application Insights resource"
            }
        },
        "hostingPlanName": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 1,
            "defaultValue": "sudipta-ase-plan1"
        },
        "skuName": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "F1",
            "allowedValues": [
                "F1",
                "D1",
                "B1",
                "B2",
                "B3",
                "S1",
                "S2",
                "S3",
                "P1",
                "P2",
                "P3",
                "P4"
            ],
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Describes plan's pricing tier and capacity. Check details at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/"
            }
        },
        "skuCapacity": {
            "type": "int",
            "defaultValue": 4,
            "minValue": 1,
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Describes plan's instance count"
            }
        }
    },
    "variables": {
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
            "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "tags": {
                "displayName": "HostingPlan"
            },
            "sku": {
                "name": "[parameters('skuName')]",
                "capacity": "[parameters('skuCapacity')]"
            },
            "properties": {
                "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]"
            }
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
            "name": "[parameters('webSiteName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "tags": {
                "[concat('hidden-related:', resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]": "Resource",
                "displayName": "Website"
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]",
                "[resourceId('microsoft.insights/components/', parameters('appInsightsName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "name": "[parameters('webSiteName')]",
                "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]"
            },
            "resources": [
                {
                    "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
                    "name": "appsettings",
                    "type": "config",
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', parameters('webSiteName'))]"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY": "[reference(concat('microsoft.insights/components/', parameters('appInsightsName'))).InstrumentationKey]"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
                    "name": "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AzureWebSites",
                    "type": "siteextensions",
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', parameters('webSiteName'))]"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
            "name": "[parameters('appInsightsName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Insights/components",
            "location": "East US",
            "tags": {
                "[concat('hidden-link:', resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/', parameters('webSiteName'))]": "Resource",
                "displayName": "AppInsightsComponent"
            },
            "properties": {
                "applicationId": "[parameters('appInsightsName')]"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**Sample ARM that does not work:**

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "webSiteName": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 1,
            "defaultValue": "TestWebsiteWithAppInsight",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Describes the name of the new website"
            }
        },
        "appInsightsName": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 1,
            "defaultValue": "test123",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Describes the name of the Application Insights resource"
            }
        },
        "hostingPlanName": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 1,
            "defaultValue": "sudipta-ase-plan1"
        },
        "skuName": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "F1",
            "allowedValues": [
                "F1",
                "D1",
                "B1",
                "B2",
                "B3",
                "S1",
                "S2",
                "S3",
                "P1",
                "P2",
                "P3",
                "P4"
            ],
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Describes plan's pricing tier and capacity. Check details at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/"
            }
        },
        "skuCapacity": {
            "type": "int",
            "defaultValue": 4,
            "minValue": 1,
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Describes plan's instance count"
            }
        }
    },
    "variables": {
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
            "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "tags": {
                "displayName": "HostingPlan"
            },
            "sku": {
                "name": "[parameters('skuName')]",
                "capacity": "[parameters('skuCapacity')]"
            },
            "properties": {
                "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]"
            }
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
            "name": "[parameters('webSiteName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "tags": {
                "[concat('hidden-related:', resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]": "Resource",
                "displayName": "Website"
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "name": "[parameters('webSiteName')]",
                "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]"
            },
            "resources": [
                {
                    "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
                    "name": "appsettings",
                    "type": "config",
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', parameters('webSiteName'))]"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY": "['99f330eb-ae79-4070-b8b6-e50d01f6e391123134434sdfdadaa']"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
                    "name": "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AzureWebSites",
                    "type": "siteextensions",
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', parameters('webSiteName'))]"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: jesus, edit it so its readable

Answer (score 0):

Please change the code from `"APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY": "['99f330eb-ae79-4070-b8b6-e50d01f6e391123134434sdfdadaa']"` to `"APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY": "99f330eb-ae79-4070-b8b6-e50d01f6e391123134434sdfdadaa"`.

**For string value should be no brackets: [ and ]**. Brackets [ and ] are used for [ARM template functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions).

> You add functions in your templates by enclosing them within brackets: [ and ], respectively.

**Update:**

> I am passing the Intrumentation key of the previuosly created app insight in the web app however they are not getting linked.

Based on my test, if want to link to Azure webapp, you also need to add the following code. **It also works with an existing appInsightsName.**

```
 {
            "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
            "name": "[parameters('appInsightsName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Insights/components",
            "location": "East US",
            "tags": {
                "[concat('hidden-link:', resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/', parameters('webSiteName'))]": "Resource",
                "displayName": "AppInsightsComponent"
            },
            "properties": {
                "applicationId": "[parameters('appInsightsName')]"
            }
        }
```

ARM template I used

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "serverFarmName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "tomfreePlan"
    },
    "serverFarmResourceGroup": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "CXP-TomSun"
    }},
  "variables": {
    "webSiteName": "[concat('TomARMTest-1', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]",
    "existingApplicationInsight": "tomarmtestdemo"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "[variables('webSiteName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "location": "southcentralus",
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "dependsOn": [
      ],
      "tags": {
        "[concat('hidden-related:', resourceId(parameters('serverFarmResourceGroup'), 'Microsoft.Web/serverFarms', parameters('serverFarmName')))]": "Resource",
        "displayName": "TomARMTest"
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "[variables('webSiteName')]",
        "serverFarmId": "[resourceId(parameters('serverFarmResourceGroup'), 'Microsoft.Web/serverFarms', parameters('serverFarmName'))]"
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "name": "appsettings",
          "type": "config",
          "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('webSiteName'))]",
            "[resourceId('microsoft.insights/components/', variables('existingApplicationInsight'))]"
          ],
          "tags": {
            "displayName": "tomtest"
          },
          "properties": {
            "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY": "xxxxxxxxxxx"

          }
        },
        {
          "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
          "name": "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AzureWebSites",
          "type": "siteextensions",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', variables('webSiteName'))]"
          ],
          "properties": {
          }
        }
      ]

    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
      "name": "[variables('existingApplicationInsight')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Insights/components",
      "location": "East US",
      "tags": {
        "[concat('hidden-link:', resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/', variables('webSiteName'))]": "Resource",
        "displayName": "AppInsightsComponent"
      },
      "properties": {
        "applicationId": "[variables('existingApplicationInsight')]"
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {}
}
```

Comment: The app insight does not get attached with the web app even without the brackets around the instrumentation key. It will be great if you can take this template and share a template that works.

Comment: Based on my test, if want to link to Azure webapp, you also need to add the following code. It also works with an existing appInsightsName. I also updated the answer.

Comment: It creates a new app insight using the template you shared. I want to link the existing app insight.

Comment: In your case you need to change `existingApplicationInsight` to your existing app insight name.

Comment: Yes i did it however a new app insight component with the same name got created in a different resource group. I need to use the app insight created previously. Also, i also need to link the app insight even when the state of the ARM file is not maintained i.e. once i create it in a resource group  all the web apps or api apps created in different resource group should point to the same app insight. In your example that does not happen.