# Link application insights to Azure web app through powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-application-insights, azure-webapps

I'm trying to link new application insights to existing Azure web app through Powershell with the below script. I'm able to create a new app insight but unable to link the new app insight to the existing Azure web app.

```
$appInsights = New-AzResource -ResourceName 'MyWebsite09' -ResourceGroupName 'Test' `
-Tag @{ applicationType = 'web'; applicationName = 'sample1'} `
-ResourceType 'Microsoft.Insights/components' -Location 'North Central US' `
-PropertyObject @{'Application_Type'='web'} -Force

$appSetting = @{'APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY'= $appInsights.Properties.InstrumentationKey}
Set-AzWebApp -Name 'sample1' -ResourceGroupName 'Test' -AppSettings $appSetting
```

Comment: The commands seem correct. What error did you face?

Comment: I'm not facing any error. This command is executing successfully in powershell which is  creating new app insight in the RG but it is unable to link the new app insight to existing webapp.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Powershell commands to link application insights with exisiting azure web app  . As your code will not enable the application insights , Follow the below code

```
$app = Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName "AppMonitoredRG" -Name "AppMonitoredSite" -ErrorAction Stop
$newAppSettings = @{} # case-insensitive hash map
$app.SiteConfig.AppSettings | %{$newAppSettings[$_.Name] = $_.Value} # preserve non Application Insights application settings.
$newAppSettings["APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY"] = "012345678-abcd-ef01-2345-6789abcd"; # set the Application Insights instrumentation key
$newAppSettings["APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING"] = "InstrumentationKey=012345678-abcd-ef01-2345-6789abcd"; # set the Application Insights connection string
$newAppSettings["ApplicationInsightsAgent_EXTENSION_VERSION"] = "~2"; # enable the ApplicationInsightsAgent
$app = Set-AzWebApp -AppSettings $newAppSettings -ResourceGroupName $app.ResourceGroup -Name $app.Name -ErrorAction Stop
```

You can [Refer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/azure-web-apps?tabs=net#enabling-through-powershell) to this MS DOC for linking application insights to azure web-app fully.

or, You can even refer the [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51821739/how-to-add-application-insights-for-existing-azure-webapp) thread for more details .

Comment: Tried this new commands but still app insight is not getting linked with webapp.... This command is executing successfully with out any error in powershell but after execution can't see application insight linked with web app.

Comment: Check ,If the application insight extension  is upgraded or not . 

Click on [troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/azure-web-apps?tabs=net#enabling-through-powershell) Fot further details.

 [Refer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-exceptions) this for application insight exception .

Comment: If the above provided answer is helpful, Could you please mark it as solution So that it will help to other community members who have similar issue in future.

Comment: Hi Ajay, if we want to check the application insight extension is upgraded or not, we need to add application insight to web app and then only we can check it is upgraded or not. If we don't enable application insight we are getting a below error message when checking application insight is upgraded or not.
"No route registered for '/ApplicationInsights'"  
But the problem is I have a webapp which was not linked to any application insight. I need to attach app insight to my webapp through powershell or Arm template. Tried the script but it is not giving any output or error.

Comment: Could you please refer the link provided by me in the answer. 
Also you can refer to the given [link](https://winterdom.com/2017/08/01/aiarm) .

Comment: Yes, I have referred the link which you have shared in answer. I have tried the powershell script in the link which was not working fine for my application. If I'm trying to update application insight extension without enabling application insight to web app it is throwing me an error. Error - "No route registered for '/ApplicationInsights'". This error can resolve only if we enable app insight to web application.

Comment: If want to link application insight to your webapp , Based on your scenario Could you please refer this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48019463/integrate-an-already-created-azure-application-insight-with-an-api-app-in-app-se) thread .

Comment: Hi, I'm able to resolve this issue through powershell commands, which was working fine in Azure Portal cloudshell. Please find my implementation code in Answer section.

Answer (score 0):

The below commands work for me in Azure portal CloudShell. After implementing the below code we were able to link New Application insight for existing webapp.

Code:

$resourceGroupName = "****"

$resourceName = "***"

$appInsightsInstrumentationKey = "***"

$app = Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $resourceName -ErrorAction Stop

$newAppSettings = @{} # case-insensitive hash map

$app.SiteConfig.AppSettings | %{$newAppSettings[$*.Name] = $*.Value} # preserve non Application Insights application settings.

$newAppSettings["APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY"] = $appInsightsInstrumentationKey; # set the Application Insights instrumentation key

$newAppSettings["APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING"] = "InstrumentationKey=$appInsightsInstrumentationKey"; # set the Application Insights connection string

$newAppSettings["ApplicationInsightsAgent_EXTENSION_VERSION"] = "~2"; # enable the ApplicationInsightsAgent

$app = Set-AzWebApp -AppSettings $newAppSettings -ResourceGroupName $app.ResourceGroup -Name $app.Name -ErrorAction Stop

Restart-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName "*** " -Name "***"

Please update the values and try this code in Azure Portal CloudShell.

Note: The code is not working for me in  Windows Powershell ISE application.